# Nested Routing for React.JS

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a question about react routing. I am making something like a clone for an e-commerce site.

My question is :

How would you make navigation for categories? I already made nav for cats. but I am not sure what is the best way to routing inside of the cat.

For example: If I click on SHOES, I want to render SHOES page with items or/and other categories for shoes?

Link for live site : https://nedim-bajric.github.io/nike-store

Link for github repo where your can find source code : https://github.com/nedim-bajric/nike-store

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested `<Route>` tags in react-router, e.g., when using the new react-router v6:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/shoes">
    <Route path="/" element={<AllShoes />} />
    <Route path="/womens" element={<WomenShoes />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

and

```
const AllShoes = () => <div>
  Here are all the shoe sub-pages:
  <Link to="/shoes/womens">Women Shoes</Link>
</div>;
```